# cd : An object at the specified path does not exist

Tags: g++

I have just study C++ for 3 days ago and I want to practice it on my PC. But when I'm done with that MinGW stuff and installed VSCode, trying to compile my first code for the first time, I meet this error:

```
 ***cd : An object at the specified path C:\Users\MYPC~1 does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ cd "C:\Users\MYPC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\" ; if ($?) { g++ tempCodeRunn ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-Location], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Argument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand***
```

Comment: Have you followed the official tutorial [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw)?

Comment: @MakeMeSmarterEveryDay I have installed mingw but they say install mingw from msys2, so do I have to uninstall mingw then reinstall mingw from msys2 ?
(sorry for such a stupid question but I'm completely new)

Comment: Follow the instructions given in the official tutorial. And let us know at what step you got stuck. This way makes us easier to understand what is going on in your machine.

Comment: Have you registered the `bin` folder of mingw to `PATH` variable?

Comment: @MakeMeSmarterEveryDay OMG I compiled it, thank you so much

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.